# How to add columns from certain fields when joining 2 tables that have matching ID's?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, cars and dealerships.

```
CARS: id, make, model, year, dealership_id
DEALERSHIPS: id, name, address
```

Cars has a dealership_id attribute but not the dealership name. How can I add that dealership name in the when joining the table if the cars.dealership_id and dealership.id match up?

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT cars.make, cars.model, cars.year
FROM cars 
JOIN dealerships cars ON cars.dealership_id = dealership.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT cars.make, cars.model, cars.year, dealerships.name
FROM cars
JOIN dealerships ON cars.dealership_id = dealerships.id
```